# How do I use screen-space derivatives to antialias a parametric shape in a pixel shader?

Tags: hlsl, fragment-shader, antialiasing

In [Valve's Alpha Tested Magnification](http://www.valvesoftware.com/publications/2007/SIGGRAPH2007_AlphaTestedMagnification.pdf) paper, it mentions using "per-pixel screen-space derivatives" for doing anti-aliasing. My understanding is that this is the `ddx` and `ddy` intrinsic functions in HLSL?

I'm trying to draw parametric shapes (for example a circle: **x² + y² < 1**) in a shader, and I don't know how to use this technique to correctly anti-alias the edge pixels of my shape. Can someone provide an example?

For completeness, here is an example of the kind of pixel shader I'm making:

```
float4 PixelShaderFunction(VertexShaderOutput input) : COLOR0
{
    float dist = input.TexCoord.x * input.TexCoord.x
               + input.TexCoord.y * input.TexCoord.y;
    if(dist < 1)
        return float4(0, 0, 0, 1);
    else
        return float4(1, 1, 1, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Taking your example, you have a step function of the distance, which produces a perfectly hard (aliased) edge.  A simple way to antialias the circle would be to turn that into a soft threshold, like:

```
float distFromEdge = 1.0 - dist;  // positive when inside the circle
float thresholdWidth = 0.01;  // a constant you'd tune to get the right level of softness
float antialiasedCircle = saturate((distFromEdge / thresholdWidth) + 0.5);
return lerp(outsideColor, insideColor, antialiasedCircle);
```

Here I used a clamped linear ramp  for a soft threshold function, but you could also use `smoothstep` or something else.  The `+ 0.5` is to center the ramp on the mathematical location of the edge.  Anyway, the point is that this function smoothly changes from `outsideColor` to `insideColor` over some range of distances, so if you pick `thresholdWidth` appropriately you'll get an antialiased-looking edge.

But how should you choose `thresholdWidth`?  If it's too small, you'll get aliasing again, and if it's too large the edge will be overly blurry.  Moreover, it'll generally depend on camera position: if `dist` is measured in world-space or texture-space units, then a `thresholdWidth` that works for one camera position will be wrong for another.

Here's where the screen-space derivatives come in (yes, they're the `ddx` and `ddy` functions as you guessed).  By calculating the length of the gradient of `dist` you can get an idea how rapidly it's changing in screen space and use that to estimate the `thresholdWidth`, like:

```
float derivX = ddx(distFromEdge);
float derivY = ddy(distFromEdge);
float gradientLength = length(float2(derivX, derivY));
float thresholdWidth = 2.0 * gradientLength;  // the 2.0 is a constant you can tune
```

You still have a value you can tune to get the desired level of softness, but now you should get consistent results regardless of camera position.

Comment: Good answer - the code works nicely. +1 and accepted. But could I trouble you to expand on your answer and explain *why* this works? I'm a bit confused about what `derivX` and `derivY` actually represent.

Comment: @AndrewRussell Are you familiar with derivatives, as in calculus?  `derivX` and `derivY` are just (approximations of) the partial derivatives of whatever expression you pass into `ddx` and `ddy`, with respect to screen-space x and y.  If you haven't studied calculus, that is a bigger topic than I can explain here. :)

Comment: My calculus is a bit rusty - I had to go and re-learn what a *partial* derivative is. But from there I think I've got it figured out. Thanks :)

Comment: OpenGL doesn't support ddx/ddy so in those cases you might need this http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch25.html which basically uses a precomputed texture to identify the mipmap level used, to approximate ddx/ddy.

Comment: @Runonthespot OpenGL has derivatives; they're just called something else: [`dFdx`/`dFdy`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/dFdx.xml) instead of `ddx`/`ddy`.